# Kendo-TreeList : Footer template only at the root level of TreeList

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treelist

I need to show some aggregates data at the root level node of tree list i.e at the bottom of the tree list, not at each node if the tree has more then one node. Can anyone suggest a way to hide the footer template except at the root node and show total or aggregates data at the root level node of tree list only . I am attaching screenshot of my requirement.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the below mentioned link for the solution :

https://www.telerik.com/forums/footer-template-only-at-the-root-level-of-treelist#5416710

Thanks